# Android: How can I get Date of call?

Tags: android

I am trying get date of call but it's returning value of 1.1.1970(I think that is some default value).

Source code:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

callDate = c.getColumnIndex("date");
int callDateInt = c.getInt(callDate);
String callDateStr = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(callDateInt);
```

callDateStr is returning 1.1.1970.How can i fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a type **long** rather than **int** to hold your date value (millisecs since epoch).  Value is overflowing the int.

Replace:

```
int callDateInt = c.getInt(callDate);
```

with:

```
long callDateInt = c.getLong(callDate);
```

Comment: It is returning same value (1.1.1970)

Comment: Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
when I am using the above cursor I am getting error,
I tried with 

callDate = c.getColumnIndex("date");